# Having trouble to change the content of a specific meta with JQuery

Tags: jquery, meta-tags

I'm trying to change the content of a meta with JQuery, but I get this error :

```
unrecognized expression: [name=dc.description]
```

with the following code:

```
$('meta[name=description]').attr('content', data.Description);
$('meta[name=dc.description]').attr('content', data.Description);
```

The meta name is "dc.description" (meta used for stats purpose). When I change the content of the meta "description", it works flawless.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `.`.

```
$('meta[name=dc\\.description]')
```

Comment: Thanks James, i didn't know about that one !

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the selector because the `.` denotes a class name.

```
$("meta[name=dc\\.description]").attr('content', data.Description);
```